# How do I find the UUID of a file system?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, partition

I'm running [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), and want to find out the `UUID` of a particular filesystem (not partition). I know I can use `e2label /dev/sda1` to find out the file system label, but there doesn't seem to be a similar way to find the `UUID`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I'm sure I will use them all in different circumstances.

Comment: Note that the title used to be "How do I find the UUID of a partition".  That question only makes sense when using a GPT partition table. [Here's an an answer to that question](http://serverfault.com/a/607402/158759).

Comment: Related: *[What is UUID, PARTUUID and PTUUID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375548/what-is-uuid-partuuid-and-ptuuid)*

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Another command that might be available and also works quite well for this is '[blkid](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid)'.  It's part of the e2fsprogs package.  Examples of its usage:

Look up data on */dev/sda1*:

```
topher@crucible:~$ sudo blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="727cac18-044b-4504-87f1-a5aefa774bda" TYPE="ext3"
```

Show UUID data for all partitions:

```
topher@crucible:~$ sudo blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="727cac18-044b-4504-87f1-a5aefa774bda" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/sdb: UUID="467c4aa9-963d-4467-8cd0-d58caaacaff4" TYPE="ext3"
```

Show UUID data for all partitions in an easier-to-read format:
(Note: in newer releases, `blkid -L` has a different meaning, and `blkid -o list` should be used instead)

```
topher@crucible:~$ sudo blkid -L

device     fs_type label    mount point    UUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1 ext3             /              727cac18-044b-4504-87f1-a5aefa774bda
/dev/sdc  ext3             /home          467c4aa9-963d-4467-8cd0-d58caaacaff4
```

Show just the UUID for /dev/sda1 and nothing else:

```
topher@crucible:~$ sudo blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda1

727cac18-044b-4504-87f1-a5aefa774bda
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu computer, I don't need to use sudo.

Comment: Just typing `blkid`, got me exactly what I wanted, but not quite what I asked for. ( I'm accepting it anyway, because I am sure I will use it often )

Comment: On newer versions of Ubuntu the equivalent command for `blkid -L` is now `blkid -o list`; the `-L` option has been changed to `-L label` to look up a device that uses the specified label.

Comment: @aculich I've updated the answer to included the recent syntax for `blkid`.  Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Excellent, I never knew about `blkid`; I've always just done `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`. On Gentoo, `blkid` is in `sys-apps/util-linux`

Comment: Heh, I like the option given by @AdmiralNemo

Comment: Warning: Be sure to run blkid as root (use sudo), so you get the current UUID for each connected device, and not an old one from blkid's cache.

Answer (score 12):

**For GPT Partitioned Disks Only**

On a GPT formatted disk each partition is assigned a GUID, which is a form of UUID, though probably not what the original poster was referring to. Therefore this answer is probably less helpful to the original questioner. Nevertheless I believe there's an important distinction to be noticed.

To get the GUID of partition 1 on GPT formatted disk */dev/sda*, as well as its partition label and so on:

```
sudo sgdisk -i 1 /dev/sda
```

or all with:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid
```

To boot with the root of the file system being on a certain partition you would use the Linux kernel parameter syntax of:

```
root=PARTUUID=87654321-4321-4321-abcd-123456789012
```

In this case, you can specify just the beginning of the UUID—enough to be unique. This parameter is more primitive and can be understood by the kernel earlier in its boot process.

---

There's a difference in semantics between these:

A disk holds partitions, a partition holds a file system, a file system holds directories and files. For some setups and operating systems there are more layers.

The GUID UUID and associated label refer to a partition, but not the partition's contents. A new partition on the same disk, or a partition on a new disk will have a new GUID UUID. The same partition could hold one file system one day and another on a different day. It only exists for GPT-formatted disks, but not for legacy partitioned disks. There usually aren't anymore utility here than specifying `root=/dev/sda1` or `root=8:1`.

The other current answers refer to the UUID of a *file system* in some containing partition. If the file system is copied, as a whole, to another partition or hard disk that value remains the same. This UUID is useful in finding a moved file system. Therefore this is probably more pertinent to most people. Linux kernel parameter `root=UUID=87654321-4321-4321-a567-123456789012` refers to this.

I believe `root=LABEL=` and `root=UUID=` are implemented by early userspace, the init code I saw the other day on my system translated these parameters to */dev/disk/by-uuid* and */dev/disk/by-label* (links I believe are created by [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) in userspace on my system).

[1] *[devt_from_devname()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/do_mounts.c#n183)*

Comment: Correct usage appears to be `-i1` or `-i 1`, as opposed to `-i:1`, with sgdisk 1.0.1.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for finding that error. I've edited the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 10):

The script-clean way to do this which works on any type of filesystem is:

```
lsblk -no UUID <device-containing-FS>
```

Or, given the mountpoint (or any file within it):

```
lsblk -no UUID $(df -P <file> | awk 'END{print $1}')
```

The output is the UUID, the whole UUID, and nothing but the UUID.

Comment: It's better than `blkid` in the answer  from @christopher-cashell, because you don't need to become root. For a mount point or a file better do: `lsblk -no UUID $(findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target <file>)` .

Comment: @marcz That fails on btrfs subvolumes: `findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target ~` gives: `/dev/mapper/vg_svelte-home[/@home]`

Comment: Right @tom-hale, `lsblk -no UUID $(findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target <file> | cut -d[ -f1)` should get rid of the subvolume when present.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this for ext2/ext3/ext4 is:

```
/sbin/tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
```

Comment: This will work provided your filesystem is formatted as ext2, ext3 or ext4. Most filesystems are one of these but not all. It will also not work for swap partitions. See my answer for a universal way.

Comment: This results in my case into `Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to do this is to do

```
sudo vol_id -u /dev/sda2
```

For more on using UUIDs, see [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) (from Ubuntu help, but it should work for any Linux distribution using UUIDs).

As noted in comments to this question, *vol_id* may not be in your path. On Ubuntu, it is in */sbin*, so the above will work.

For [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux), it appears to need:

```
sudo /lib/udev/vol_id -u /dev/sda2
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my Fedora 10 laptop.

Comment: This is a much better solution than mine. Eddie, vol_id is located in /lib/udev. mish, could you edit your answer to prefix the full path in front of vol_id? /lib/udev isn't in root's path by default on any distribution I'm aware of.

Comment: "/lib/udev/vol_id /dev/sda2" appears to work.  Few people will have /lib/udev in their path.

Comment: On my Ubuntu computer there is a symbolic link from `/sbin/vol_id` to `/lib/udev/vol_id`

Comment: Even though this is exactly what I asked for, `blkid` would have been more useful, when I went to edit `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: **vol_id** has been dropped from Ubuntu as of Karmic (9.10) so isn't useful or relevant anymore. It went through a lot of contortions to get there as **vol_id** was at one point built to replace **blkid**.

Comment: *Why* is it the recommended way? Why is it better? Who recommends it?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep UUID
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the UUID for *sda1*, you could try something like this:

```
for v in /dev/disk/by-uuid/* ; do echo "`readlink $v`: $v" | grep ../sda1 | cut -d\: -f2 | cut -d/ -f5 ; done
```

Adjust *sda1* accordingly. To get the UUIDs for all partitions, drop the 'greps' and 'cuts', a la:

```
for v in /dev/disk/by-uuid/* ; do echo "`readlink $v`: $v" ; done
```

Sample output for *sda1* on my desktop:

```
[mihailim@home ~]$ for v in /dev/disk/by-uuid/* ; do echo "`readlink $v`: $v" | grep ../sdb3 | cut -d\: -f2 | cut -d/ -f5 ; done

dc8c49f1-e2dc-46bc-ba02-013f26c85f70
```

Please note that this solution, while more contrived than the *udev->vol_id* one, does **not** require root privileges, will work on any post-2005 or so kernel, and relies on tools present in any Linux distribution which are by default in the path for any user.

Comment: This will work on any computer running a recent enough devfs.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and best way to find the UUID of a filesystem:

```
blkid /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Does this add anything to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this to print all the UUIDs:

```sh
for disk in /dev/disk/by-uuid/*; do 
    basename "$(readlink "$disk")"
    basename "$disk"
    echo
done
```

or this arguably simpler command, replacing `sda1` with the device you'd like to search for:

```sh
disk=sda1
find /dev/disk/by-uuid -type l -exec sh -c "readlink {} | grep -o $disk && basename {}" \;
```

an adaptation of the second method to print all UUIDs:

```sh
find /dev/disk/by-uuid -type l -exec sh -c 'basename $(readlink {}); basename {}; echo' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep `lsblk | grep "/" | awk '{print $1}'` | awk '{print $9}'
```

The above seems to work on most (all I have found) Linux systems over many years.  It may have flaws, I don't know.  I would prefer to get the serial number but ... this is the UUID of the root filesystem.

If anyone has a way to get the serial number without needing to be root (as mine is) and not installing "unusual" packages that are different in different versions of Unix I would appreciate it - always can learn something.  And I am aware I am mixing things - the is the root file system UUID, not a disk.

The purpose, BTW, is to generate a unique number per machine that cannot be modified (like a disk serial number and like MAC addresses once were long ago).

It is used for encoding of software to a single machine.  MAC address was fine until they allowed them to be virtual ...  some sleazy customers have simply set their MAC address to a constant (on different networks of course) and avoided paying me.

In AIX there is a single call to get one number that identifies the machine.  It does not care if the hardware changes or software updates occur so I have no idea how they do it ... If the motherboard changes, then the number changes, so I think they hide it there.  And that is beyond rare.

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"the is the root file system"*.

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building - *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the UUID for a particular drive,

```
sudo vol_id -u /dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the UUID for a particular drive,

```
sudo vol_id -u /dev/sda1
```

or you can use this to list all UUIDs for the attached media,

```
ls /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Comment: No longer applicable as of Ubuntu 9.10 as **vol_id** has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo grep swap /etc/fstab
## Output like:
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
# UUID=34e3f31b-16ec-4c84-8f4d-339f38d04a3b none swap sw 0 0

sudo lsblk -f -l| grep SWAP
## Output like:
sda6 swap 34e3f31b-16ec-4c84-8f4d-339f38d04a3b [SWAP]
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. For example, what is the conclusion? How does it answer the question? What is the gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://serverfault.com/posts/1116758/edit), not here in comments (***** ***** ***without*** ***** ***** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).